# Invoking python lambda with arguments

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple lambda function which accepts an argument and prints it.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   temp = event["temp"]
   return {
      'statuscode': 200,
      'body': json.dumps(f'Hello from {temp}!')
   }
```

I've enabled function url in lambda and set authorization as None. Without any arguments, `curl https://xxxx.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws` works.

Using Test through the console, I get the correct output, but not through a curl call.

```
curl -X POST https://xxxx.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"temp":"Hello World"}' \
> 
Internal Server Error%
```

Comment: It's worth getting familiar with debugging Lambda functions via CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: True, it was right there haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a step in your code. You have to extract the `body` first from the `event`, and then you can extract the `temp` attribute from the `body`, for example like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   body = json.loads(event['body'])
   temp = body['temp']
   return {
      'statuscode': 200,
      'body': json.dumps(f'Hello from {temp}!')
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked like a charm. I got confused with how I used to do with google cloud functions. Should start looking at cloudwatch logs, dumb of me.